# Ingest Kafka csv files cell by cell

Tags: csv, apache-kafka, data-ingestion

I have this csv structure dataset:

|  | S1 | S2 | ... | Sm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1.6 | 2.4 | ... | 0.5 |
| A2 | 1.8 | 0.1 | ... | 3.2 |
| .. | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| An | 0.3 | 4.1 | ... | 2.6 |

I want ingest a document for each cell in the csv like this to be ingested in kafka:

{
"sample_id": "Sm"
"attribute:_id": "An"
"expression": 2.6
}

This files have a size from 1Mb to 700Mb aprox.

What will be the best option to ingest this csv files in kafka to be indexed later in elasticsearch?